# Options for correcting a sagging ridge line on a garage that is missing rafter ties

Tags: framing, roof, garage

I have a house with two attached garages. I'm not sure of the year of the second garage, but the house (and presumably first garage) was built in 1972. We live in a snowy climate.

The second garage is about 32' x 16'. There's a shop area framed out in the back of the garage. The roof has rafters 16" OC and has a few problems:

- The ridge is not a single piece. The last few feet are butted together with another piece and joined with some thin plywood.
- There are no rafter ties and four collar ties
- There has been movement in some of the rafters. Some are a bit twisted; some have separated from the rafters.

As a result, the ridge line of the garage is noticeably sagging. I don't think there's anything I can do about the poorly-framed ridge, but I think I can mitigate further damage.

I think the correct solution is to:

1. Put a beam directly under the ridge and set this on the top plate of the exterior wall (on one side) and a metal fastener onto the wall on the other side. This beam would have a post (but off-center so a car could still be parked in the garage) for support. Jack up the ridge and install some vertical members between the new beam and the ridge.
2. Install rafter ties on every-other rafter. These would sit on top of the new beam
3. Remove the jack

Is this the correct course of action or are there better solutions? I'm probably going to get estimates from a few contractors as well, but would like to be educated and understand potential solutions first.

Below are some photos of the issue:

**Photo 1:** the wall of the other attached garage is on the left. The place where the beam is broken is between the 2nd and third rafters. Notice the 4 collar ties
[image]

**Photo 2:** another angle of where the ridge piece ends.
[image]

**Photo 3:** Another angle of the ridge. You can see how the joists near it have twisted and moved.
[image]

**Photo 4:** Facing towards the exterior wall (the break in the ridge is directly overhead of where the photo was taken)
[image]

Comment: Do you notice the walls that the roof rafters sit on pushing out at the top?

Comment: The length of the ridge is ~16'?  So then the rafters are 18-20' long, assuming a 30 deg pitch on your roof?

Comment: @SteveSh If I check with a 4' level, the walls are very slightly bowing out, but I don't see any visual signs of movement (it could be the walls were never quite plumb to begin with). You are correct; the ridge is about 16' and the rafters are about 17-18' long.

Comment: Your question has a few red flags. For example you mention trusses but there are no trusses in any of your photos and a roof system with rafters is vastly different than a roof system with trusses. Anyway are you sure you don’t want to hire a structural engineer? If not, and I would seriously question why not, at a minimum I would start by adding some metal brackets, like Simpson RR rafter to ridge board ties. I’d also add hurricane ties to where the rafters meet the top plates. But please get an engineer involved.

Comment: You should keep in mind that in gable-framed structure with rafters, the gable end walls are almost always non-structural. In most cases, the ridge beam is also not structural and just gives the rafters something to be nailed to. Gable end structures are held up by the exterior long walls and rafters pulling against each other. That’s why one of the first questions we ask is if the walls are starting to pull out. If the walls are pulling away from each other, it will indicate the structural problem.

Comment: Doing what OP suggested is going to turn his roof from a ridge board design into a ridge beam design, or some mishmash of both.  This changes the way the loads are carried, particularly at the ends of the beam that need to bear on a post of the correct size.  This needs a structural engineer to provide guidance.

Comment: Adding ceiling joists (~32' long) that tie the two walls that the rafters rest on together will help prevent further bowing of the walls, but will not correct the current problem.

Comment: I’m also a fan of getting an engineer involved. Part of the solution will almost certainly involve pulling the tops of the walls in while jacking the ridge up.

Comment: @RibaldEddie I had one typo where I swapped rafter with truss. I'm aware they are different. What other "red flags" does my post have?

Comment: I'm not opposed to bringing in a structural engineer at all. As I said in my post, I wanted a better understanding of the issue and what potential solutions are involved before bringing in another party.

Comment: @SteveSh you might be able to just add a beam running perpendicular to the ridge and resting on the walls rather than ceiling joists. Even a built up beam of a few 2x12s can be sufficient. Again — OP needs an engineer.

Comment: As I suggested, what you want to think about is keeping the walls plumb — adding a second beam parallel to the existing ridge board will not work well because the gable ends don’t have the needed structure to support the weight of a true ridge beam.

Comment: In other words, if you’re going to add support, look at adding supports that are perpendicular to the ridge board and bearing on the walls. So that’s ceiling joists / a ceiling beam.